# Do these polynomials have a name?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Playing around with some ideas, I came up with a set of polynomials of this kind:
\begin{equation}
P_n(x)=x\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i+h)-(x+h)\prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i)
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ and $h$ are complex numbers.
I am trying to factor these things up but am stuck. Maybe the community will recognize something known?

Comment: What is $h$? What are the $x_i$?

Comment: If you set $x_0 = -h$, then $P_n(x) = Q_n(x+h) - Q_n(x)$, where $Q_n(x) = \prod_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $n+1$.  So the polynomial $P_n(x)$ is perhaps related more or less easily to divided differences of some interpolation problem.

Comment: @vonbrand, they are just parameters, no deep meaning.